# timer not incrementing a variable in timer tick

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i use a timer to incrementing a count variable

in front i use timer with updatepanel to update just a modalpopupextender like this

```
       <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer2" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" Enabled ="false"> </asp:Timer>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
                  <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
        <div id="Pingdialog">
        <asp:Panel ID="pn1" runat="server"  Style="display: none; background-color:White; border: solid 1px silver;" >
        <asp:Panel ID="pn2" runat="server"  Style="cursor: move; background-color: silver;
            border: solid 1px Gray; color: Black; width:300px;" >
            <div style="width:100%;" >BizView : </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div style="text-align:center; width:100%; margin-top:20px; font-size:18px; ">
            <asp:Label ID="lblpingmes" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:textbox ID="txtpingmes" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="multiline" AutoPostBack="true"  Visible="false"></asp:textbox>

            <p style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="100px" />
            </p>
        </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div style="display: none;"><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="." /></div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalping" runat="server" TargetControlID="button2"
        PopupControlID="pn1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="Button1"
        OnOkScript="onOk()" DropShadow="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="SubPopup" BehaviorID="savepingmodal" />

    </div>   


</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in code behind

i use btn to `enabled` a timer event

```
Partial Class 
    Dim countpingcheck As integer

    Protected Sub btnPing_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPingATM.Click
        pinglog(lblIP.Text.Trim)
        modalping.Show()
        Timer2.Enabled = True

    End Sub
```

then when timer start do

```
Public Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    countpingcheck += 1
    modalping.Show()
    If countpingcheck < 5 Then
        lblpingmes.Text = countpingcheck
    Else
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        checkip()
    End If
End Sub
```

i have a variable `countpingcheck` will increment +1 per tick but it's stuck on count = `2` I don't know why, then  i tried to debug  it's loop just  0,1,2

Comment: Keep in mind that a new instance of your page will be created on every post back, so `countpingcheck` will reset to 0 every tick unless you are persisting its value on the page somehow.

Comment: The best approach would be to use timer instance for each session. Once the session is gone dispose the timer object too. If you need details let me know.

Comment: thank you @AJRichardson i follow your suggest and i solved it by change from `dim` to `shared` and it's work !

Comment: I would caution AGAINST shared as it will be shared across ALL users of your website. I'll try and post an answer with a different approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, a new instance of your page will be created on every post back, so `countpingcheck` will reset to 0 every time. To fix that, you need to persist its value on the page somehow. One way is to use a hidden fiend inside the `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCountPingCheck" runat="server" />
        <!-- You other controls would be here; skipped for brevity -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
Public Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim persistedCountPingCheck as Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(hiddenCountPingCheck.Value, persistedCountPingCheck) Then
        countpingcheck = persistedCountPingCheck
    End If
    countpingcheck += 1
    hiddenCountPingCheck = countpingcheck.ToString()
    modalping.Show()
    If countpingcheck < 5 Then
        lblpingmes.Text = countpingcheck
    Else
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        checkip()
    End If
End Sub
```

I apologize if there are syntax issues; my VB is a bit rusty.